# Drag and drop picturebox disappears

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am having problem with my code. I am trying to make a drag and drop of a picture on my form, but when I move the selected picturebox it gets lost when I go out of the group box. It just disappears.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x_offset = 0; // any better to do this without having a global variable?
    int y_offset = 0;

    PictureBox dpb = new PictureBox();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
        this.pictureBox2.MouseDown += pictureBox2_MouseDown;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
        x_offset = e.X;
        y_offset = e.Y;

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
            me.Left = e.X + me.Left - x_offset;
            me.Top = e.Y + me.Top - y_offset;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PictureBoxes are being clipped by the parent (which is GroupBox). You can either fix the hierarchy (View->Other windows->Document Outline).

Also, generally it is better to use standard drag and drop functionality, like described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92cad3ba-dd05-4aa9-ad44-411051407d57/drag-and-drop-picturebox-to-picturebox-in-c?forum=csharplanguage. That will take care of all the drag and drop special cases. In order to change the standard cursor, set the Cursor.Current to the cursor, returned by CreateCursor(myBitmap). Note: CreateCursor may potentially fail in some cases, so make sure to provide a fallback to standard cursors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be better to summarise what's behind the link in your answer, so it isn't lost if the link goes stale. Otherwise, great job with your first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PictureBox` has a `GroupBox` as its Parent, in `winforms` and many other UI technologies, you can't render a child control outside its parent control. You may want to do something like this before using your code:

```
pictureBox1.Parent = this;//set your Form as Parent of the pictureBox1
pictureBox1.BringToFront();//Ensure your pictureBox1 is on top.
```

If your requirement is to drag-n-drop your `pictureBox1` from the `GroupBox` onto another control to make it as the new `Parent` of your `pictureBox1`, you can try the following code:

```
    Point downPoint;
    //MouseDown event handler for your pictureBox1
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        downPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Parent = this;
        pictureBox1.BringToFront();
    }
    //MouseMove event handler for your pictureBox1
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            pictureBox1.Left += e.X - downPoint.X;
            pictureBox1.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y;
        }
    }
    //MouseUp event handler for your pictureBox1
    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 1, pictureBox1.Top));
        if (c == null) c = this;
        Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(pictureBox1.Parent.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location));
        pictureBox1.Parent = c;
        pictureBox1.Location = newLoc;
    }
```

Comment: thanx a lot for ur information however i need to leave the selected picture box at its position and just drag and drop a copy of the image. so my quation is how can i leave the original picturebox and only take a copy of it that i will drag. Kind regards :)

Comment: @ToshkoKosev both your question and your code **showed** that you wanted to move your `pictureBox`, You didn't even mention anything related to what you said in your comment here.